# Relations and Cartesian Product: why does $X^1$ differ from $X^0$ and $X^2$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations, function-and-relation-composition

**Question** Why are functions of a single variable specified with a tuple argument $(x)$ as in $f(x)$, when this pattern suggests they should be specified without parenthesis as $fx$?

This pattern

(1):
$$
X = \{a\}
$$
$$X^n = X \times ... \times X$$
$$
X^0 = \{()\}, X_0() = T, () \in X^0 
$$
$$
\mathbf {X^1 = \{a\}, X_1(a) = T , a \in X^1}
$$
$$
X^2 = \{(a,a)\}, X_2(a,a) = T, (a,a) \in X^2
$$

where $X_n : X^n \rightarrow \{T,F\}$

The pattern continues $X^n, n>2$.  If we follow the pattern, $X^1$ would be elements of tuples ($f :\mathbb N \rightarrow X$):

(2):
$$
\mathbf{X^1 = \{(a)\}, X_1(a) = T , (a) \in X^1}
$$
With this, the predicate is the relation's symbol $X_1$ and the object is the ordered tuple $(x_0, ..., x_n)$.  This case is not true, which means the predicate may have either a tuple or individual as it's object.

To be consistent with the pattern, it would seem the relation $X$ does not take an ordered pair $(a)$ as an argument and is without parenthesis:
$$
\mathbf {X^1 = \{a\}, X_1 a = T , a \in X^1}
$$
but I know an ordered pair $(a)$ is typically given as an argument.  Given this, it appears the parenthesis is syntactical and does not form an ordered tuple.

If the pattern (2) is followed the notation for composition becomes more clear, $f : X^1 \rightarrow X^1$, $f = \{((a),(a))\}$ then $f(a) = (a)$ and the composition is just $f...f(a)$.  Otherwise with pattern (1) composition requires the syntactical brackets $f(...f(a))$.  Again, with a tuple, $g : X^3 \rightarrow X^3$ would be composed $g(g(x))$ with these extra syntactical parenthesis vs $g.g(x)$ which is confusing.

Comment: What the heck are "$X^1a = T$" or "$X^2(a,a) = T$" even supposed to mean? This is no standard notation. Neither is $()$, but it is fairly obvious what that one should be.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I updated the OP to address this better.  Those are predicate functions that we mislabeled and I correct that.

Comment: Basically, the answer to your question is that we do not consider $(a)$ and $a$ as distinct objects. If $(a)$ is just an alternative form of saying $a$, then both notations are the same, and it follows the same pattern. In that way, you can treat $X^1 = X$, and not worry about the difference. On the other hand, if you want to insist $(a) \ne a$, then $X^1 \ne X$ and your non-pattern line is a mistake. The correct line would follow the pattern. Either choice is fine, and internally consistent. But you have to understand that others are free to make a different choice than you do.

Comment: I agree, $f(x) := fx$ I think it's a one way equality, otherwise there would be too many parenthesis.  I have seen $fx$ in older literature as well.

Comment: Not every thing in parentheses is a tuple. $f(x)$ is not meant to be $f$ acting on the tuple $(x)$, but rather the parentheses are just there to delineate where the argument of $f$ begins and ends. This way you can write expressions such as $f(3x + 2)$ with no ambiguity. Conversely, the expression $f3x+2$ is highly ambiguous. Is it $f(3)x + 2$ or $f(3x) + 2$ or $f(3x + 2)$? It is not just old texts that use $fx$. It is a very common practice in linear algebra. But only in cases where it is not ambiguous.